# Why a getCount() of a query returns me 1 if the value its empty?

Tags: android, sqlite

the question is simple, i have this query

```
 Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT printer2 FROM tableAreas", null);
```

why reason returns me 1 if the value in the table is empty, it should return me 0 right?

Greetings.

Comment: I guess getCount() returns the numer of records and not if the value is NULL or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is any record of your table named **tableAreas**. If there is any record found via cursor, cursor returns the number of record. if you are getting 1 that means you have one record in your table. If your values are empty in your record, it does not matter. It will count that row as a record entry.